# Bucket fill different shades accrodingly to target area colour/alpha

Tags: gimp, graphics-editing

In GIMP, I'm using the "Bucket Fill" tool to add colour to a black surface. The shape I am filling includes different shades of black/grey, with different alpha values, as can be seen in the image below:

[image: original, unfilled shape]

Adjusting the "Threshold" option allows for the Bucket Fill tool to affect areas with different colours that touch each other, either vertically-horizontally, or that and diagonally. This is a great option, but I have yet to find a way to fill different shades of the new colour automatically, according to the different shades of the target colour affected by the threshold value.

As an example of what I would like to *avoid*, here's an image:

[image: shape filled with desired colour, but undesired pixelated effect]

As you can see, the desired colour for the object is all uniform, which gives it an undesired rough and pixelated look. How do I avoid this?

**P.S.** I would have liked to graphically show what effect I want to achieve, but if I *could* show you, using an image that I've created, then there would be no need for the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Gimp well enough to know if there's an equivalent - though there's usually a way to do anything Photoshop can do. In Photoshop I'd do this with a Hue/Saturation overlay, with the 'colorise' setting on. This will change the colour value of every pixel, without affecting anything else. [I just guessed the colour, didn't measure it.]

[image]

The paint bucket is a blunt instrument, it can't really manage this kind of subtlety. It will either fill a pixel or it won't. Anti-alias is then applied without reference to the existing edges.

---

Gimp apparently has Colourise separate in the Tools > Colour Tools menu [again, complete guess on the actual colour]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it. Yeah, makes sense. In fact, I have not found a similar tool, but I have found a workaround, using another layer which consists of a plain orange square, adding it over the original image, and making the new layer mode "addition". It obviously only works for a purely greyscale image, but it is possible to do it on any image successfully after having taken its saturation down to zero percent. I will post my solution as an answer when I have the time. Thanks again for your answer. That's what gave me the idea. Cheers.